# How to update multiple data to Database?

Tags: vb.net

Does anyone knows how to fix this code to and make it work properly?. I want to update my DB that will get the value in `Combo box`. Is it possible to update 1 or more value at the same time in DB?

### **CODE**

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE tblStudent SET (course = '" & ComboBox2.Text & "',section = '" & ComboBox5.Text & "') WHERE yearLevel = '" & yearLevel.Text & "';"
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You should read up on SQL injection, as this has quite a few problems...

Comment: Also, read: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d11ed406-d9bf-4363-84b6-99f4e9ee4631/how-to-insert-data-into-sql-table-using-vbnet

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use sql-parameters instead of string concatenation to prevent possible sql-injection.

Also, your code  already updates multiple records if there are more than one with the same `yearLevel`.

```
Dim sql = "UPDATE tblStudent SET course = @course,section = @section WHERE yearLevel = @yearLevel"
Using cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, con)
    Dim p1 As New SqlParameter("@course", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    p1.Value = ComboBox2.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p1)
    Dim p2 As New SqlParameter("@course", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    p2.Value = ComboBox5.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p2)
    Dim p3 As New SqlParameter("@course", SqlDbType.Int)
    p3.Value = Int32.Parse(yearLevel.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p3)
    Dim updatedCount = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

Note that i didn't know the data -type of your columns, so modify it accordingly. I just wanted to show you that it's important to use the correct type in the first place.

Comment: i'm not certain, but does ComboBox5.Text automatically receive the selected value?

Comment: @jbutler483: [`ComboBox.Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.text(v=vs.110).aspx) is the text of the currently selected item.

Comment: I was thinking that but something made me think there was a case where that didn't work. But I'm not an expert :P

Comment: @jbutler483: yes, if nothing is selected. But i assume that OP handles that already.

Answer (score 0):

This is is for 'INSERTING', however, it can be adapted for 'UPDATING' quite easily:

```
Dim con As New SqlConnection
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
Try
con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=atisource;Initial Catalog=BillingSys;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=12345678"
con.Open()
cmd.Connection = con
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table([field1], [field2]) VALUES([Value1], [Value2])"
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Catch ex As Exception
MessageBox.Show("Error while inserting record on table..." & ex.Message, "Insert Records")
Finally
con.Close()
End Try
```

source: [can be found here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d11ed406-d9bf-4363-84b6-99f4e9ee4631/how-to-insert-data-into-sql-table-using-vbnet)

where you have declared `field1`, and assigned it `Combobox2.SelectedValue` etc